# Why does a javascript method loose connection with the object when used with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, this

The code below prints out:

```
timedout false undefined
```

I.e. `this` is no longer refering to `theActivityTimer` in method `timedOut()`. I was wondering why this was.

```
var theActivityTimer = {
    timer: "",          
    active: false,       

    refresh: function () {
        theActivityTimer.timer = setTimeout(
            this.timedOut,
            5000     
        );
    },

    timedOut: function(){
        alert("timedout " +
            theActivityTimer.active + " " + this.active);
    }
}

theActivityTimer.refresh();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spiderplant0/nQ4XX/

And is there a way to tell get it to work with `this`

Comment: It doesn't *lose* connection with the object; it never had a connection in the first place. The only thing that matters for the value of `this` is how a function is invoked.

Comment: thanks @pointy, could you elaborate please (as this  doesnt really explain anything)

Comment: Unlike languages like C++, Java, C#, etc, declaring a function as "part of" an object doesn't actually result in there being any strong relationship between the function and the object. Such a function in JavaScript is just like any other function, and the only relationship involving the object is from the object to the function, as a property value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is based on how the method is invoked.

```
foo.bar(); // this === foo

var bar = foo.bar();
bar() // this === window (defaults to global object)
```

So `setTimeout` effectively does the latter.

Instead, it's common to pass an anonymous function that maintains the proper call to your instance method.  Just remember that the anonymous function will also lose `this`, so you need to save what `this` is to a local variable, which is also common.

```
var self = this;
theActivityTimer.timer = setTimeout(function() {
    self.timedOut()
}, 5000);
```

---

There are other ways to manipulate context (the value of `this`), but this one is probably the  easiest to understand and the most widely supported.

Comment: -1 I'm putting my foot down on this. I appreciate the "easiness" of this answer, but you're doing no favors in terms of teaching actual good practices. Having context variables floating around your scripts is a recipe for complete disaster. I know `fn.bind` is newer, but `fn.call` and `fn.apply` are very widely supported.

Comment: Thanks very much, as its a object literlal initialiser I used: `function(){theActivityTimer.timedOut();},`

Answer (score 3):

This question is asked all the time; You'll want to use [`fn.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
var theActivityTimer = {
    timer: null,          
    active: false,       

    refresh: function () {
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.timedOut.bind(this), 5000);
    },

    timedOut: function(){
        alert("timedout " + this.active);
    }
};
```

---

From the [fn.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) docs

> Creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

---

**Disclaimer:**

`fn.bind` was implemented in ECMAScript **5**. If you're using this in a browser and need to support older versions, check out [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

---

Comment: why this.timeout.call(this) ? when you can do exactly the same thing with this.timeout()? two codes are always identical. And here that is a problem since 'this' is not available

Comment: in your alternative code, var self = this, or var that = this is actually necessary.

Comment: Thanks v much for the explanation (I need IE8 compatibility though so went with other answer)

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another solution to this thread to add inline solution that does not need any extra work or library and is cross-browser.

```
var theActivityTimer = {
    timer: "",          
    active: false,       

    refresh: function () {
         theActivityTimer.timer = setTimeout(function() {
             theActivityTimer.timedOut();
         }, 5000);
    },
```